# Using envoy as a reverse proxy for a remote site after auto login

Tags: go, envoyproxy

I am trying to establish the following flow

- Envoy receives request from client to access remote site S1
- Envoy routes the requests to Cluster C1 - which fetches the required credential, performs login
- C1 extracts the required cookies and session information
- The page redirects to the remote site which is proxied back from envoy

To achieve this

- Need to set the required cookies and session information to the redirected page
- The envoy should continue to act as reverse proxy
- I do have the logic to fetch the required cookies and if I use reverse proxy in Golang it works. However, I need to do this using envoy.

Some thoughts

- Configure initial route for internal redirect
- Once Cluster c1 fetches the credentials, it will add the required information to the request and redirect
- Unclear about what should happen next how to achieve the reverse proxy behaviour. The remote site is not fixed so it has to be dynamic.

Answer (score -1):

Without implementation details of cluster C1 it’s not possible to determine if it’s going to work for you, but sound like you need external authorization HTTP filter: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.18.3/configuration/http/http_filters/ext_authz_filter.